# React js reset state of a component if the parent component has re-rendered

Tags: reactjs

So I have that situation:

I have a `MovieList` component that loop through `Movie` components,

and In each `Movie` Component there is `Text` component that has a state to "ShowFullText" or not ( the default is not to show the full text ) and this stateful component has a button to show the full text which works just fine.

Now, let's assume you search for some other movies and then search again the Movie you expanded its text, well it's still expanded

So what I would like to know is how if the parent component (`Movie`) changed, ( for example disappeared and then in the future will come back ), its sub-components state's will reset to default?

Comment: It would be easy if you would have share your code but I think you can have a prop in your movies component let say showFull, just pass this prop as false for every movie in the loop.And in your movie component set the default state for ShowFullText as props.showFull. So whenever your movies will get render, it will set the ShowFullText in the movie component to false.

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb so the state should move from `Description` up to `MovieList`? then I'll face the Prop Chain Problem?

Comment: Can you share the code? It would be easier for me to answer and also for you to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in at least two ways.

### 1st

Render child components with search string passed as prop:

```
list.map( (movie, idx) => <Movie key={idx} searched={searched} data={movie} />)
```

Of course `<Movie />` should react on prop change - f.e. by `useEffect` (dependency - 2nd arg on `[props.searched]`), `shouldComponentUpdate()` (props/state saving/comparison) or `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

### 2nd - react [recommended way](https://pl.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recap)

Force recreating of all listed childs by using unique `key` property, f.e. derived from search string. This can affect performance (for long lists).

```
list.map( (movie, idx) => <Movie key={`${idx}_${searched}`} data={movie} />)
```

using template literals or simple strings (first argument):

```
list.map( (movie, idx) => <Movie key={searched + idx} data={movie} />)
```